# Setting up multiple MediaElement sources with jQuery

Tags: jquery, mediaelement.js

I have MediaElement set up to play some audio. I know how to change the source with JavaScript, the problem is I need to have both a `.mp3` source and a `.ogg` source and I can't figure out how to set both.

Right now I have it set up to change one source. This works, I just need to be able to have both for compatibility.

```js
mediaElement.addEventListener('ended', function (e) {

  mediaElement.setSrc("audio/budget_2.ogg");
  setTimeout(function () {
    mediaElement.play();
  },1000);

}, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Per [the source](https://github.com/johndyer/mediaelement/blob/39a42d0646aa6641ef342a4dfa5415abaca80c24/src/js/me-mediaelements.js), `setSrc()` can take either a single string, or an array of URL/type objects.  e.g.

```
mediaElement.setSrc(
  [ { src: 'audio/budget_2.ogg', 'type': 'audio/ogg' },
    { src: 'audio/budget_2.mp3', 'type': 'audio/mpeg' }
  ]
);
```